# Tslint 'semicolon' option not yelling after type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4, tslint

I've turned on the `semicolon` option in [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) and before entering a Git issue, I wanted to know if anybody in the community knows if this is as designed or not.  Should the `private resolvedCampaign : Campaign` below be throwing a lint error?

```
///<reference path="../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

class MyClass {
  private resolvedCampaign : Campaign

  constructor(resolvedCampaign : Campaign) {
    this.resolvedCampaign = resolvedCampaign;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it should error and it isn't very different from the issue found here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/254

Where this code doesn't error on the semicolon rule.

```
interface ITest {
    foo: string
}
```

The difference with your code is that it is on an interface property.
I think it is best to add a comment on issue #254 with your code and hopefully it will get fixed eventually! :)

Comment: Ha, I was actually going to do that, but I didn't want to piggy back on your issue.  Since this is a separate issue, I'll create a new one.